# ES 7.4.1 - Authentication [Rest API]

Tags: java, authentication, elasticsearch, certificate, elasticsearch-x-pack

I’m a newbie in ES and I have a task in my new job to upgrade from 6.4.2 to 7.4.1 – From TCP client to Rest High Level API.

Previously we built the client like this:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
      .put("xpack.security.user", String.format("%s:%s",esJavaUser,esJavaPassword))
      .put("cluster.name", esClusterName)
      .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", xpackSecurityTransportSslEnabled)
      .put("xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities", xpackSslCertificateAuthorities)
      .build();

 client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings);
```

Now, in rest API, it’s changed to this:

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
        new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(esJavaUser, esJavaPassword));

RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(hosts)
        .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
```

With this build I set ES user and password by CredentialsProvider **but** what about `ssl.enabled` and `certificate_authorities”`? how should I provided them with rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from ES forum (didn't thought to ask there first..)

Because, as developer, I always looking for answer here, in stackoverflow, I decide to not delete this question and copy [TimV](https://discuss.elastic.co/u/timv/summary) answer:

The documentation you are looking for is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.4/_encrypted_communication.html

SSL is automatically enabled (or not) based on the scheme (protocol) in the `HttpHost` objects you pass to the builder.

> RestClient.builder(hosts)

If you are using SSL, you want to pass `"https"` as the scheme (3rd argument) when you construct the `HttpHost` objects (`hosts`).

Unfortunately there is no simple means to pass `certificate_authorities` to the Rest client, you need to turn those certificates into a standard Java truststore.
You can probably find some sample code on the web ("convert PEM certificates to Java truststore"), but the gist of it is:

1. Open the certificate authority files as an `InputStream`
2. Create a X.509 certificate factory: `java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")`
3. Call `generateCertificates` on the certificate factory to read those certificate files into java `Certificate` objects
4. Construct an empty `KeyStore` object
5. Add the loaded certificates as trusted entries
6. Pass that to `SSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial`

Link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-7-4-1-authentication-rest-api/211969